# Display custom message from signal in the admin

Tags: django

I have a pre-save signal listener that updates a second model. The same as this example:

- [Django Signals to update a different model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954499/django-signals-to-update-a-different-model)

I'd like to let the user know that the listener succeeded in updating the model and provide some information. Normally, I would think I could use the built in messages functionality that django has. The problem is that the signal doesn't have access to 'request'. So I can't see how to use the built in Django Messages Framework.

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/

Is there a known method for sending a message to the user in the admin? Maybe by overriding the save() method for one of the models? (the one sending the signal, or receiving), but I don't think the save() method has access to 'request' either?

This must be something others want to do as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can override [save_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods) method in ModelAdmin. Something like this:

```
from django.contrib import messages
# your imports
...
# your code

def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.user = request.user  
    obj.save()
    # you can just call super(YourModelAdminName, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
    messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Text of message')
```

Comment: what's the difference between save() and save_model()? When I looked into save() it doesn't have those arguments? And when is it called? I found save_model() in the docs, but I don't see this information.

Comment: Sorry, but there are no save() method in ModelAdmin. Only save_model().

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The messages aren't displayed.